# Blue Menu does not appear during Pop Up in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

On our company website http://exciga.com/Services.php# when one clicks on any of the services on the right hand side (ex: the IT Governance image), a Window Pops Up with information regarding IT Governance along with a Blue Menu on the left hand side. This Blue Menu can be seen in IE 10 but not in Chrome. Please help as I cant figure out what I have done wrong :-)

The 2nd issue I face is in the Service Lists. When I click on the list of Services (ex: the "+"sign near IT Governance), I get a list of services related to it. As you can see the fonts are different here. I am unable to place the same font as in the Service List header ("IT Governance"). If I try making a change, the font for the entire webpage changes. I want the font in the drop down list to be the same as the one in the Service List header ÏT Governance +" Hope I was clear for u guys.

Finally, what is the syntax to ensure that the size of an object does not change if I Zoom in and out in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

First fix `<head>` section, you have included multiple jQuery libraries, if your plugins can work with latest jQuery (you should test it) then I suggest you to download [jQuery 1.10.2](http://jquery.com/download/) put it in your `js` folder and replace `<script src="js/jquery-1.6.js" ></script>` with `<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`.

---

Now replace your `<head>` element with this new one and I wish you luck ;) P.S. I don't say that this will fix the problem you have.

```
<head>

  <title>Exciga</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Write short description of your site here.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="write, site, keywords, here, like, this, comma, delimited">
  <meta name="author" content="Name of the site author">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css"> <!-- Why style2.css ? Is this another style for entire site or you could merge style.css with style2.css ? -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hover/style_common.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hover/style2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.akordeon.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/application-d7d505356b55e600106ef945bd484e9f.css">

  <script src="js/jquery-1.6.js"></script>

  <!-- These scripts you can/should put just before the </body> tag, if after that some elements lose functionality then put that script again in the <head> section -->
  <script src="js/atooltip.jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.akordeon.js"></script>
  <script src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
  <script src="js/cufon-replace.js"></script>  
  <script src="js/Vegur_300.font.js"></script>
  <script src="js/PT_Sans_700.font.js"></script>
  <script src="js/PT_Sans_400.font.js"></script>
  <script src="popup/custom.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/application-aa8aaa30c70f4a42013dec916e9b29b0.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#buttons').akordeon();
         $('#button-less').akordeon({ buttons: false, toggle: true, itemsOrder: [0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7] });
      });
  </script>
  <!-- End of scripts -->

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="all">
  <![endif]-->
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <div style="clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;">
      <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode">
        <img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." />
      </a>
    </div>
  <![endif]-->

</head>
```

---

**Update:** About `font-family` for the `Service Lists` open `style.css` and insert code below then change font family and size in accordance with your desires.

```
.responsive,
.responsive-half {
  font-family: Verdana !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your quick reply. Will take a look soon.

Answer (score 0):

The blue menu is actually present in Chrome. It's just that it's getting hidden by the pop up window's size: `<div class="popupbox3_pm" id="popuprel3" style="display: block; margin-top: -355px; margin-left: -380px;">`, which is its parent element. Because this `<div>` has `position: fixed;` and a set width/height, anything outside of its dimensions gets cut.

I'm not quite sure why the `z-index: 999` on the blue menu is not setting it above the black space around it though. That might have to do with the placement of the element in the HTML. Also, it should have a higher z-element than the black fade box, which has `z-index: 9999;`.

Comment: I agree, just check both IE10 & Chrome v.31 and the blue menu is present and it shows the same way.

Comment: Thanks guys. The world goes around with good people like you.

Comment: Gentlemen, its not working after a few trial & errors. Could you please be kind enough to let me know what exactly it is that u would like me to do for those 2 issues. I am using IE10 and Chrome v.31 but the blue menu is not showing in Chrome.....Thanks.